# Handling runtime exceptions in UI

Tags: java, exception

Suppose my web application throws a runtime exception due to some reason.
When that happens, I want to capture it and show a proper message in the UI rather than a 501/505 error.
What is the best way to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something lik ethis in your **`web.xml`**

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
    <location>/app/error/commonErrorPage</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/app/error/404ErrorPage</location>
</error-page>
```